# Cannot connect to VM VirtualBox Linux Nginx server after restarting my computer

Tags: linux, nginx, connect, virtual-machine

I recently setup an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server running nginx, and I could connect to it via its IP address. However, after restarting my computer I can no longer connect to the server in any browser but I can connect via SSH through puTTy. No clue what's going on and ifconfig shows that the IP address has not changed and I changed no settings on the server. How can I fix this?

This picture shows the chrome window response when I try to access the server, the ifconfig from the server (top right), the network settings on the VM (bottom left), and the location settings for /etc/nginx/sites-available/www.

[server settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeZGE.jpg)

I have tried restarting, doing an nginx reload, and a full computer restart. Nothing has worked so far. All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: make sure that the service is working, `sudo service nginx status`

Comment: I tried out `sudo service nginx status` and was returned with the message 'nginx is not running'. How do I start nginx?

Comment: `sudo service nginx start`, if it didn't start then there's a config error.

Comment: yep, `sudo service nginx start` didn't do anything.

Comment: what config errors would commonly cause this issue?

Comment: check `/var/log/nginx`, probably `error.log` if no other error log was defined in the config.

Comment: Found the problem. Thank you!

Comment: I'll group the comments into an answer, would be nice if you can vote it for me :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure that the service is working using `sudo service nginx status`

If it's not running try starting it manually `sudo service nginx start`

If it fails to start, you can check the error log in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` or any other error log defined in the server config.