# How to connect to nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, dns

I am following the tutorial [here](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2012/11/how-to-set-up-a-safe-and-secure-web-server/2/) to set up a server. I installed nginx and checked my version with `nginx -V` (nginx/1.5.6).

The tutorial says: "If you've done everything right, accessing your Ubuntu server's IP address or DNS name in a web browser should yield the [nginx welcome page]."

I logged in to ssh with `myname@serverIPaddress` and now I copied and pasted `serverIPaddress` to browser but I get the "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to serverIPaddress"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question. The problem was `nginx` was not running:

```
root@b:~# sudo service nginx status
 * nginx is not running
root@b:~# sudo service nginx start
 * Starting nginx nginx                       [ OK ] 
root@b:~# sudo service nginx status
 * nginx is running
root@b:~#
```

Now entering the IP address of the server takes me to the correct page.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247549/cannot-connect-to-vm-virtualbox-linux-nginx-server-after-restarting-my-computer).